# Get IMEI number in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, imei

I need IMEI for validation in a React Native app. Using reactive-native-imei package, here is the link to that package: (https://github.com/SimenCodes/react-native-imei).

during my code I am getting the following errors:-

1. In my Code here;

```
const GetImei = () => {
    const IMEI = require('react-native-imei');
    IMEI.getImei().then(imeiList => {
        console.log(imeiList); // prints ["AABBBBBBCCCCCCD"]
    });
```

In the second line of my code `const IMEI = require('...react-native-imei');` It is giving me that 3 dots below 'r' of react-native-imei and when I hover over it, it's saying "could not find declaration file for module- 'react-native-imei' ", though I have installed the package and also linked it, I also checked In the node-module the package is still there also I have checked settings.gradle file the package is included there so what could be the reason of this error? please help me.

2. some other errors I am getting are given in the below images:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

check this issue. It is raised in library.

https://github.com/SimenCodes/react-native-imei/issues/22

If you are in a very particular situation, you can use this library in recent Android versions as well. "Just" follow Android's rules for obtaining the extra permission. There's some hints in the discussion from 2019, but you should know that the permission has been renamed to READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE since then.

check in android documentation also.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes?authuser=1#non-resettable-device-ids

Comment: So it means we cant access the IMEI number now in react-native? Is this what it says?

Comment: No. we will get IMEI number once we have READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission. Which is already explained in Doc above.

Comment: So if I change <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> to 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" /> will it be OKAY?

Comment: Just give it a try. Place permission in androidmanifest.xml file and request runtime permission through PermissionsAndroid.

Answer (score -1):

I dont actually know what exactly caused the error in your application but I have build a demo base on your given library and it works fine. Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity ,Text,View} from 'react-native'

export default class Demo extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      deviceIMEI: '',
    }
  }

  getIMEI = () => {
    const IMEI = require('react-native-imei')
    this.setState({
      deviceIMEI: IMEI.getImei(),
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{this.state.deviceIMEI}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getIMEI}>
          <Text>Get Current Device IMEI</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
})
```

Comment: What about "In the second line of that code "const IMEI = require('...react-native-imei');" It is giving me that 3 dots below 'r' of react-native-imei and when I hover over it, it's saying "could not find a declaration file for module- 'react-native-imei' ", though I have installed the package and also linked it, I also checked In the node-module the package is still there also I have checked settings.gradle file the package is included there so what could be the reason of this error?"

Comment: I am running your code now it is giving me an error : Objects are not valid as a React child  (found: object with keys {_U, _V,_W,_X}).