# Unable to fetch IMEI number of a mobile device using React-Native

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, imei

I have type-script code for a mobile app. I want to fetch the IMEI code of the device when I log into the app. I have linked react-native-imei (android) library with react-native successfully, but when I add following code at login, I do not get the number:
const IMEIObj = require('react-native-imei');

```
IMEIObj.getImei().then((imeiList: any) => {
    console.log("imei", imeiList); // prints ["AABBBBBBCCCCCCD"]
})
```

Instead I get the following error:
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ReactNative.NativeModules.IMEI.getImei')

I have been on this for 2 days, but couldn't move ahead. Can you please help me here? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377596/get-imei-number-in-react-native

Comment: According to the other issue, you need to have the right permission in order to be able to read the IMEI

Comment: can you tell me how to add permission in AndroidManifest file. The code in other places weren't clear. My phone's android version is 9